# Variable Named Ranges in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Excel formatted as follows:

```
Date      Asset Return
1/3/2005    0.003582399
1/4/2005    -0.01908258
1/5/2005    0.002080625
1/6/2005    0.005699497
1/7/2005    -0.008040505
1/10/2005   -0.00339116
1/11/2005   -0.009715187
1/12/2005   0.002371855
1/13/2005   -0.00580783
1/14/2005   0.001058481
1/18/2005   0.015483842
1/19/2005   -0.014690715
1/20/2005   -0.015714799
1/21/2005   -0.010796326
```

I need a named range to reference each column. The workbook is a template, so the named range won't always cover the same number of rows depending on the data. I want to set it so that the named range "Date" and the named range "Asset Return" are automatically sized to cover the entire column from the first value until the last, without going past the last value in the column.

It will always start at cell B8, but might end at a different row depending on the size of the data.

How can I set a dynamic named range to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This named range formula will do it:

```
=Sheet1!$B$8:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)+8)
```

Remember to add the sheet name as the named range will operate on the active sheet otherwise.

The formula starts takes B8 as it's starting point: `Sheet1!$B$8`
It then counts how many cells are not blank in column B:  `COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)`
It adds 8 to the count (assuming your first rows are blank).
It then uses `INDEX` and the `COUNTA` to reference the last cell.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509

Comment: I would prefer `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$8,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B),1)`

Comment: Wow, never knew items in colon range notation could be calculated!! Great!

Comment: You can use `OFFSET`, but that's a `volatile` function unlike `INDEX`.  Meaning it will recalculate every time Excel recalculates regardless whether precedent data is changed (pretty much copied that word for word, so here's the link: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).

Comment: I was returning to this old code and just had a quick question for you. How would I adjust this formula to apply to a range rather than a column, for instance A:K starting from A1? I tried to change the formulas accordingly but without success.

Comment: If the only data in the column is the data you're after you can use `=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$K:$K,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))`.  The `INDEX` is returning column K.  `COUNTA` should still be referencing a column that doesn't have any blank cells in your data set - this will tell it which row to return in column K.

Answer (score 1):

Try this VBA code

```
Sub test()
    application.DisplayAlerts = false
    Range("B8").currentregion.createnames _
        top:true, right:=false, left:=false, bottom:=false
    application.DisplayAlerts = true
end sub
```